# Intellij thinks TypeScript function names are properties

Tags: intellij-idea

After wrestling with a part of my angular app that just wouldn't work I finally found the culprit - Intellij for some reason mixes up the functions inside TS classes with properties. Example below:
[image]

get name() is clearly a function. But Intellij flags it as "unused property name". More so, once or twice the property name accessed with the getter/setter would change by itself if I changed just the function name - without doing it via refactor.

The same "unused property name" appears on top of all my properties as well. Some properties may show that tooltip, while others may not. Sometimes even properties that are not greyed out will show that tooltip.

I have disabled all my plugins and invalidated my cache. Tried to manually write the set/get instead of generation. Nothing works.

UPDATE: Tried doing this with VScode and it worked. 
[image]

I then imported the same project to Intellij and it gave another error, but now something about how the property is recursive:
[image]

Comment: there is nothing wrong in calling getters/setters properties, they are accessor properties - essentially functions that work on getting and setting a value, but look like regular properties to an external code. And marking them unused is expected if they are not used anywhere in your code. If you don't like public properties/variables/function to be reported as unused, try disabling the **Unused global symbol** in **Settings | Editor | Inspections | JavaScript and TypeScript | Unused symbols**

Comment: @lena worked like magic! Make it an answer and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing technically wrong in calling getters/setters properties, they are 'accessor properties' - essentially functions that work on getting and setting a value, but look like regular properties to an external code. And marking them unused is expected if they are not used anywhere in your code - this is a way **Unused global symbol** inspection works.

If you don't like public properties/variables/function to be reported as unused, try disabling the **Unused global symbol** in **Settings | Editor | Inspections | JavaScript and TypeScript | Unused symbols**